# Ordering PHP/SQL Results by lon/lat co-ordinates calculation

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to filter my table results and order it by lon and lat co-ordinates but it's coming up with an error for the code I'm using.  Here is the code, but I'm not sure if I'm using the correct calcultations for the ordering. Can anyone please help:

```
$keyword = //From Form Input
$lon = //From Form Input
$lat = //From Form Input
$filter = //From Form Input

$radius = 6371;

//$get_result_sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE type = '$filter' AND name LIKE '%$keyword%'";
$get_result_sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE type = '$filter' AND name LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY acos(sin($lat) * sin(lat) + cos($lat) * cos(lat) * cos(lon - ($lon))) * $radius DESC";
$get_result_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_result_sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)!=0){ //and if atleast one record is found 
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_result_res)){//This line has the error
```

Comment: First of all, don't ever concatenate input values directly in any part of a query. Do a quick search for SQL Injection. Use named/positional parameters instead.

Comment: Second, if you're asking for help about an "error", don't forget to provide the "error message". Amusingly enough, it sometimes contains clues about how to solve the problem.

Comment: @samuelgrigolato I've looked it up but I still don't get what you mean. What code should I use instead?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Sorry, the error is, Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...

Comment: @samuelgrigolato I'm using mysql_real_escape_string for all information passed through my queries, this prevents sql Injection right?

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly state that whan you call `mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_result_res)`, `$get_result_res` is *not* a valid result_set. My guess is [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) has returned FALSE. Probably because there was an error is your SQL statement.

From the doc:

> **`mysqli_query`**
>
> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

---

You next step now should be to somehow *print* the query is order to spot the problem. BTW, [mysqli probably allow you to obtain some meaningful error message](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) *from the DB server* on case of failure...

Comment: I'm getting the error that I said above, so it's not returning any values

Comment: Well yes, that's why I'm asking if there's an error with the calculation? This query works fine without the ORDER part

Comment: @user2516546 I understand. But that's why I said you should at the very least `print($get_result_sql)` and maybe read mysqli::$error. I bet this is only a very minor thing like a missing quote or an uninitialized variable...

Comment: I'm passing the data through Ajax and I'm not sure how to echo out the print($get_result_sql) statement?

Comment: I added '' to the ORDER BY query and it now works (`acos(sin('$lat')`), although I'm not convinced by the accuracy of the lon/lat results. Thanks anyway though